# WebJob "host is not running". How to debug?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

An Azure Websites WebJob is online with no deployment errors and no errors visible on the WebJob SCM consoles for the deployed WebJobs at any level except for this: "host not running" and some fuzzy info (see below). I can start the WebJob locally in VisualStudio 2015 and it runs perfectly, however I cannot attach the debugger to the deployed WebJob. The "parent" MVC 5 Website runs fine as a Azure Website and I can attach the debugger to it's controllers.

**What does "host not running" in this case mean and how/where can I best see what is wrong?**

What I also get in the SCM console is the following, but I'm not sure where to run the csc command. Also, I have turned on application logging verbose to table in my WebSite config which may provide more insight.

```
[08/27/2015 19:49:52 > 62f8a0: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
[08/27/2015 19:49:52 > 62f8a0: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[08/27/2015 19:49:52 > 62f8a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
[08/27/2015 19:50:57 > 62f8a0: SYS INFO] Run script 'csc.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[08/27/2015 19:50:57 > 62f8a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[08/27/2015 19:50:58 > 62f8a0: INFO] Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.0.0.50618
[08/27/2015 19:50:58 > 62f8a0: INFO] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[08/27/2015 19:50:58 > 62f8a0: INFO] 
[08/27/2015 19:50:58 > 62f8a0: INFO] warning CS2008: No source files specified.
[08/27/2015 19:50:58 > 62f8a0: INFO] error CS1562: Outputs without source must have the /out option specified
[08/27/2015 19:50:58 > 62f8a0: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
[08/27/2015 19:50:58 > 62f8a0: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[08/27/2015 19:50:58 > 62f8a0: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the published webjob has `csc.exe` file in it. You can verify by checking the webjob folder `D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\<jobName>` from [DebuConsole](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).

When the logic that runs the webjob tries to find the executable to run, it will go through them in alphabetical order. If you need `csc.exe` in your webjob but the webjob is actually in a different exe, then include a file called `run.cmd` that runs your exe. `run.*` will always take precedence over anything.

Comment: Indeed, there is a roslyn directory being copied into my bin/Debug when I deploy. This is a new phenomenon and I have no idea what is causing roslyn (and properties) to be placed in there. My Build Action for the Funcions.cs and Programs.cs is Compile, seems normal. And all are "do not copy". Any ideas?

Comment: Roslyn directory is being put there at compile-time. It is also present in the parent MVC's bin but NOT in my other two WebJob's bins, so there is a package or setting difference. The question is, how to find it. I am using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core        {5.2.3}  and .Client in the WebJob, so I am suspecting some self-hosting features there that I need to turn off.

Comment: There is a Build Rule in this package: Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0 (which I cannot seem to uninstall or find in the package manger) with <None Include="$(CscToolPath)\*"><Link>roslyn\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link> <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> causing the copy to take place for this ONE (of my 3) WebJob projects. Still looking for the dependency path so I can drop it...

Comment: OK, needle in haystack found. The package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform was causing roslyn to be copied to the WebJob bin and thus caused the problem above. I just Uninstall-Packaged and nothing exploded. I do not know why it was installed in our case. Thanks again.

Comment: Possibly related, your webjobs storage might be corrupt.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402114/host-is-not-running-requests-will-be-queued-but-not-execute-until-the-host-is-s/54692251#54692251