# Azure WebApp with C#6 and WebJobs together not possible due to csc.exe deploy?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn, azure-webjobs, c#-6.0, azure-web-app-service

I have a sort of catch-22 situation: To use C#6 in my VisualStudio 2015 MVC5 project (in particular with the Razor ViewEngine), the recommended "fix" (won't compile without it) is to install the NuGet Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform. So far so good.

Then, I deploy the WebApp with WebJobs, and I get the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254634/webjob-host-is-not-running-how-to-debug). I still cannot find a way to prevent the csc.exe and VB.exe from being deployed to my WebJobs /app_data folder and thus halting the WebJobs. I have tried to delete the above NuGet from the webjob explicitly, but it is nowhere to be found. It is being "inherited" from the parent WebApp. So, who knows how to prevent these roslyn extras (csc.exe and vb.exe) from being deployed to the WebJobs. Else, I must deinstall the NuGet from my parent project meaning no C#6 support. Catch-22.

Ideas?

Here is what is in the WebApp Web.Config. There is nothing  like it in the App.config files of the attached WebJobs.

```
  <system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
 </system.codedom>
```

Comment: Which version of .NET do you target?

Comment: .NET 4.5.2 since its release.

Comment: Could you post your web.config entry related to `system.codedom`?

Comment: Sure. It is now in the post. Also from web.config: <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />.  I assume that I can safely remove the VB CodeDom line from my config since we are pure C#?

Comment: Everything seems ok. Why do you want to get rid of csc/vb.exe exactly? They are needed for runtime compilation scenarios. Do they pose a problem that the workaround exposed by your previous question does not solve?

Comment: Yes, looks are decieving :-) That is the problem: it is not ok, it breaks my WebJobs. There is no workaround in the post that I refer to in my question, I had to deinstall the package, which then removes C#6 support. And no, csc.exe is not needed in the WebJobs - it breaks all of them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see the point of using WebJobs if you don't actually have *something* to run. Indeed, C# 6 or not, you *are* producing some kind of executable if you're creating a WebJob, and this is what you want to point the runtime to (instead of csc.exe). Anyway, I didn't say in my comment that WebJobs themselves need `csc.exe`, but it is required by the new ASP.NET runtime compilation pipeline. You can't get rid of it AFAIK (even when using precompilation).

Comment: I'm now doubting my English skills: I have a WebJob, and of course I have it to run, I just don't want the extra .exe (csc, vb) in there, since they get run instead.  These are automatically deployed by the CodeDom Nuget I mentioned above, so to remove this roslyn deploment, I currently have to remove the CodeDom which also removes my C#6 support.

Answer (score 0):

The same solution as in the question you point to should help here. i.e. include a run.cmd file with your WebJob, and use it to run whatever exe you want, overriding the default detection mechanism.

See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs for details on the detection mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have an exe to run, all I want to do is be able to use C#6. So I guess a (lame) workaround would be to include an empty run.cmd in my WebJob project root and thus trick the WebJob to not punt when it sees the csc.exe. Sounds a bit risky for a production sysem, but if this is the only fix? Two wrongs to not make a...

Comment: OK, an empty run.cmd just throws and error with the same net result. What do I have to put in the run.cmd to just continue without errors?

Comment: You must have an exe that gets produced by your VS build, no? Please use Kudu Console to look at the details of what gets deployed for your WebJob (under `site\wwwroot\app_data\etc...`).

Comment: Yes, I have my WebJob exe of course, but the other exes are blocking it from being run. How to keep them from being deployed or getting in the way without haveing to remove my C#6 support in my entire project (codedom nuget package)? I do not need csc.exe in my WebJob. I've had Kudu in use for a year, works fine, as do my WebJobs, just not with CodeDom C#6. What must be in the run.cmd to neutralize this...?

Comment: What prevents you from specifying your produced exe in run.cmd?

Comment: Yes, that would work and  I guess that is what I end up with at the moment. I had hoped to remove the cause of the problem rather than work around it with a hack, but if there is no other obvious solution. So be it. The run.cmd i mentioned above was throwing an error since I hat UTF8 encoding enabled instead of ANSI.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not a hack, this is the way it is supposed to work. Compilers deployment are required to enable Roslyn features (both at the language level and at the runtime level). And even if you'd only have one exe in your folder and there would not be any kind of ambiguity, I would still consider it a good practice to explicitly specify the function to run with a run.cmd.

Comment: Ok, call it a workaround. If this is acceptable as desired behavior, then I'm in the wrong movie: the NuGet broke parts of my system. It is not even installed in the WebJob project in question (packages.config) but still shows up there upon deploy. Also, it does not show up in my Schedued WebJobs, only in my Continuous WebJobs. Also, the WebJob documentation does not stipulate to put your exe in run.cmd (which I will now do). Thanks for your help (seriously!).