# Host is not running; requests will be queued but not execute until the host is started

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Often when I republish a webjob with some minor changed and try to Rerun a Webjob function SCM shows me the following warning in the web portal, and I cannot execute the function

> Host is not running; requests will be queued but not execute until
>   the host is started.

The host is always running in this case, and the job is setup as singleton, there should not be a problem with multiple hosts.

Comment: How long does this last? Should only be momentary. You're publishing your SDK WebJob as a Continuous job with AlwaysOn enabled, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebJobs Dashboard shows this message until it receives an updated "heartbeat" message from the host indicating that the host is running. The JobHost writes the heartbeat message into blob storage (in the **azure-webjobs-hosts** container under path **/heartbeats**). The Dashboard polls the heartbeat blob for a particular host ID and shows this message when it detects the host hasn't started running yet. There might be a *minimal* delay between when the host starts up and when the Dashboard sees the blob update.

Comment: For one of my Jobs this warning stays forever. Can this be also related to Host Id changes? What happens when Azure moves my Website to another host for some reason?
What is the interval in minutes or seconds of the "Minimal delay" usually?

Thanks

Comment: The "host" we're talking about here is not an Azure VM host, but the SDK JobHost running your jobs. For example, if your WebJob is scaled out across 3 instances, they'll all be sending a heartbeat, so only one need to be running for the Dashboard to receive the heartbeat and not show the above warning. The HostId is derived from your fully qualified assembly name. Are you changing assembly names/versions? That might be it.

Comment: Yes we increase the version numbers on updates. This seems to be the problem then. Is there a best practice for this in webjobs?

Comment: You might consider using a stable HostId by setting it manually via JobHostConfiguration.HostId - that will override the default HostId handling. Or you can ensure that your assembly names (the fully qualified name) don't change from version to version.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was not a heartbeat issue or a HostId naming change. My WebJobs were running properly in continuous mode, but could not run them individually. This happened after updating the version in AssemblyInfo.cs.

To resolve/workaround:

- Download [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/)
- On your App Service, copy the connection strings from `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `AzureWebJobsDashboard`
- Stop your WebJobs
- Connect to the web jobs storage accounts in Azure Storage Explorer
- Delete these containers and queues:

  - Containers

    - `azure-jobs-host-archive`
    - `azure-jobs-host-output`
    - `azure-webjobs-dashboard`
    - `azure-webjobs-hosts`
  - Queues

    - `azure-webjobs-*`
    - Other queues that are for your web jobs if you used custom hostids
- Start WebJobs

Comment: This solved it in my case. Now everything seems to be working just fine, although I did not change anything. Logs in the dashboard have not appeared for the last month, and manually triggering a webjob from dashboard only put it in the queue.